# T-SQL: Separate String Into Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Ex.

```
Column 1:
| word1 word2 word3 word4 |
```

to

```
 Col 1:  Col 2:  Col 3:  Col 4:
| word1 | word2 | word3 | word |
```

Is it possible to separate different words or phrases from a string into multiple columns? All words and phrases in the strings are usually separated by double spaces, nothing else. Is there a pre-defined function I can use already available from SQL Server like CAST or INTERSECT, or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a dynamic sql version. of John's in case you don't know the maximum number of words.  Key techniques to accomplish what you want would be split string and pivot (or conditional aggregation).  Because you are kind of doing both at once John's method is a nice shortcut.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TblName') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TblName
    END

CREATE TABLE #TblName (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,String VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('word1  word2  word3  word4'),('abcd  efgh  ijkl')

DECLARE @NumWords INT

SELECT @NumWords = ISNULL(MAX((LEN(String) - LEN(REPLACE(String,'  ','')))/2 + 1), 0)
FROM
    #TblName

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '
SELECT
    t.Id
    ,t.String
    ,c.*
FROM
    #TblName t 
    CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT

          '
WHILE @i <= @NumWords
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL
             + IIF(@i > 1,', ','')
             + 'Column' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '1 = x.value (''/x[' + CAST(@I AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ']'',''varchar(max)'')'

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + '
       FROM
          (SELECT CAST(''<x>'' + REPLACE(String,''  '',''</x><x>'') + ''</x>'' as XML) x) a
    ) c'


EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Comment: The maximum amount of columns is 4, so there will always be 4 columns, but if a string only has 3 words, then only 3 new columns will be used for that row. Your function is very good, but can I type in the column name as the inserted value, or do I have to write down each word, one-by-one? Each row from the original column has a different set of words for every row, and sometimes words change every day or week, so I cannot be retyping all words every time, so is there a way to make your function retrieve the words automatically from the original column?

Comment: If there will be a maximum of 4 columns I would use John's answer as this would be overkill.  I am not following what you mean would you have to write down each word as the works would be split automatically for you.  You may be getting thrown off because I named the column word1, word2 etc. So I just updated and changed that to Column hopefully that will clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of a CROSS APPLY and some XML.  Easy to expand and/or contract

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,Column1 varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'word1 word2 word3 word4'),
(2,'some other words')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
        Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
         From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(A.Column1,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
       ) B
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: This is very good, but the problem is that I do not define the list of words; the original column has multiple rows each with a different string, and I cannot write down each string one-by-one, the function needs to do it automatically, especially since strings can be different from each account and they change every day. Is there a way to make your function a bit more dynamic, so it can run with multiple variables?

Comment: @K.Ventura  The (at)YourTable is a demonstrative table variable.  Replace (at)YourTable with the your actual table name and A.Column1 with your actual field name and it will run.   When you say dynamic what exactly are you looking for,

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
Create Table AllData (Column0 varchar(500))
Insert Into AllData Values ('word1 word2 word3 word4')
Select parsename(replace(replace(replace([Column0],'  ',' '),'  ',' '),' ','.'), 4) [Col1],
parsename(replace(replace(replace([Column0],'  ',' '),'  ',' '),' ','.'), 3) [Col2],
parsename(replace(replace(replace([Column0],'  ',' '),'  ',' '),' ','.'), 2)  [Col3],  
parsename(replace(replace(replace([Column0],'  ',' '),'  ',' '),' ','.'), 1)   [Col4]

from AllData
```

Comment: There is an article explaining what the function is actually for and how to abuse it. See https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data

It also shows how to reverse the string so that the order is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you word count is not fixed numbr, you can use dynamic script, it'sa sample:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tb') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tb
CREATE TABLE #tb (id int,Column1 varchar(max))
insert Into #tb values
(1,'word1 word2 word3 word'),
(2,'w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6')

DECLARE  @Cols NVARCHAR(max),@sql nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @MaxWordCount INT 
SELECT @MaxWordCount=MAX(LEN(t.Column1)-len(replace(t.Column1,' ',''))+1) from #tb as t
    SELECT @Cols=ISNULL(@Cols+',','')+'[Col '+LTRIM(sv.number)+']' FROM master.dbo.spt_values as sv WHERE  sv.Type='P' and sv.number BETWEEN 1 AND @MaxWordCount

PRINT @Cols
SET @sql='SELECT * from (
             SELECT t.*, w.* FROM #tb AS t
             CROSS APPLY (VALUES (convert(XML, ''<n>'' + replace(t.Column1, '' '', ''</n><n>'') + ''</n>''))) x(c)
             CROSS APPLY (SELECT ''Col '' + ltrim(row_number()OVER (ORDER BY getdate()))  AS col
                                 ,s.b.value(''.'', ''varchar(200)'') AS wd
                          FROM x.c.nodes(''n'') s(b)) w
         ) a PIVOT (max(wd) for col in ('+@Cols+')) p'
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tb') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tb
```

```
id  Column1 Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4   Col 5   Col 6
2   w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6   w1  w2  w3  w4  w5  w6
1   word1 word2 word3 word  word1   word2   word3   word    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion/variation on the answer from user7075507.

There is a simple answer using/abusing the built in PARSENAME function which splits a . delimited name into 4 parts in reverse order.  **The limit is only 4 parts.**

There is an article explaining what the function is actually for and how to abuse it. See https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data

So you need to convert your delimiter to a dot reverse the string and then unreverse to get the result.

```
    Declare @YourTable table (id int,Column1 varchar(max))
    Insert Into @YourTable values
    (1,'word1 word2 word3 word4'),
    (2,'some other words')
    
    
    SELECT ID
        ,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(Column1), ' ', '.'), 1)) Pos1
        ,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(Column1), ' ', '.'), 2)) Pos2
        ,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(Column1), ' ', '.'), 3)) Pos3
        ,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(Column1), ' ', '.'), 4)) Pos4
    FROM @YourTable
```

Returns

[image]